# Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x20004018) How to solve this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

[image]

here I attached my snapshots when run my project, It shows on exception like Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x20004018, I don't no how to solve this issue ...can anyone help me??

Comment: its a exception, enable zombies and check once

Comment: I tried what u said...I am new to iOS .I don't no how to solve the exception

Comment: what the exception you got in console after enabled the zombies

Comment: [MSSTabBarCollectionViewCell setTitle:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc5ec67cb80.  (I got like this after enabled Zombies)

Comment: can you show that the code related to MSSTabBarCollectionViewCell

Comment: - (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self.textTitleLabel.text = title;
    
    self.imageTextTitleLabel.text = title;
}
- (NSString *)title {
    return self.textTitleLabel.text;
}

Answer (score 0):

Since `pageName` is a static string, it can't be the cause of this.

So, it has to be one of two things:

- `tab` was not correctly initialized prior to being passed to that method
- the `setTitle:` method on the `MSTabBarCollectionViewCell` is doing something weird.

You'll need to post more code (like how the `tab` object is initialized and how the method that is crashing is called) to get a more specific answer.

Answer (score -1):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means there is no class of instance is Execute. Check out Your pageName object. i think it is not properly decleared or Intialize

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS means the app tried to access a bad address.   The `pageName` object cannot be the cause because it is a static string.